# How do i get my code to only select a .csv attachment and not the image from within the email txt?

Tags: python, email, outlook, email-attachments, office-automation

I currently have the below code that works perfectly if the email is blank but if it comes as part of a chain and it has images (ie company logos in peoples signature etc) then it will only find those. How do i filter it to only select the .csv?

```
    import win32com.client
    import os
    import time
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    folder = outlook.Folders.Item("myemail@gmail.com")
    inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")
    msg = inbox.Items
    msgs = msg.GetLast()
    print (msgs)
    print (msgs.Subject)

    Filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = 'senderemail@gmail.com'"
    Filter = ("@SQL=" + chr(34) + "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" +
                        chr(34) + " Like 'subjectofemail' AND " +
                        chr(34) + "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" +
                        chr(34) + "=1")

    Items = inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
    for Item in Items:
        for attachment in Item.Attachments:
            print(attachment.FileName)
            attachment.SaveAsFile("U:\Downloads\Foldername\Otherfolder\\" + attachment.FileName)
      
            timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

            old_name = r"U:\Downloads\Foldername\Otherfolder\\attachmentfilename.csv"
            new_name = r"U:\Downloads\Foldername\Otherfolder\\attachmentfilename " + timestr + ".csv"

            os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

I have tried a few things ive seen on here but i am very new and have basically created this code from snippets of code i found and got it working with trial and error so im not sure what im doing really. Im trying to learn as i go but assume i need an ELI5 if possible. Thanks

Comment: Fix the formatting of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kind of attachments that should be detected:

1. Attachments with a specific extension - `.csv`. You can filter them by checking the `Attachment.FileName` property like you have already figured it out.
2. Embedded images that are used for the message body markup. You can check the message body content for the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID MAPI` property value (the DASL name is  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"). Use the `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` method for retrieving the value and then check the attachment in the message body using the `src` attribute that matches the value of `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` set on the attachment. `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` corresponds to the `Content-ID` MIME header when the message is sent.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple case of adding a line under for attachment line

```
If attachment.FileName.endswith('.csv'):
```

This then only uses the .CSV attachments